# How can I test for reflexive, symmetric, or transitive

Tags: c++

I have to use this struct in my code:

```
struct Pair
{
   int x,y;
   friend bool operator==(Pair a, Pair b)
   {
     return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
   }
   friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Pair& a)
   {
     is >> a.x >> a.y;
     return is;
   }
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Pair a)
   {
     os << '(' << a.x << ',' << a.y << ')';
     return os;
   }
};
```

I need to read a .txt file:

```
5 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
7 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 7 7 4 7 7
8 1 1 2 4 3 9 4 16 5 25 6 36 7 49 8 64
```

This file has 3 relations in it, each one starts with an int which is the number of pairs in that relation, then that many pairs follows. Then (if not eof) read another int and that many pairs again, and so on.

How can I read this data into my struct pair?

After I read it I will have to test if the data is reflexive, etc, but I am just having trouble getting started on this project.

Comment: Seems to me the code is largely there. How would you read the first pair? Do you know any way to repeat something `n` times?

Comment: i dont fully understand the overloaded istream. I cant get it to read the data. I am also not sure how to exclude the first number in the line.

Comment: You wouldn't need to exclude it, instead, just "eat" it first. My answer shows that, too

Comment: Incidentally, it's troubling that the stream inserter creates a text representation that the stream extractor can't read. These two should usually work in tandem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd write.

I know my take on it is probably a bit 'advanced' - but at least it should show you that the code required is really not that much.

On bit of explanation:

- using a string stream (`istringstream`) allows you to treat a single line as a stream. This isn't strictly necessary, but prevents things running awry if the input isn't in the expected format.
- The `friend` stream operators (in particular, `operator>>`) will allow you to "just" read a pair from a stream with a simple:

  ```
  Pair p;
  stream >> p;
  ```

  Now, this is what the code below *implicitely* does when I invoke the `copy_n` algorithm on an `istream_iterator<Pair>` (i.e. it extracts `Pair`s in exactly the same fashion as I just showed).

```
using Pairs = vector<Pair>;

int main()
{
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);

        unsigned n;
        Pairs pairs;

        if (iss >> n)
            copy_n(istream_iterator<Pair>(iss), n, back_inserter(pairs));

        if (!iss)
            return 255;

        std::cout << "Read a line with " << n << " pairs (check: " << pairs.size() << ")\n";
    }
}
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e857f03ff619756)** with the sample  input from the question, printing:

```
Read a line with 5 pairs (check: 5)
Read a line with 7 pairs (check: 7)
Read a line with 8 pairs (check: 8)
```

Comment: I was just typing an explanation (see the edited answer). Think of a vector as an _array_ but with dynamic sizing (the `back_inserter` will automagically grow the "array" (i.e. vector) instead of you worrying about allocating and freeing memory.

Comment: @user1082764 you could try to learn. If your code has statements such as `friend` and operator overloading, I would be concerned that you don't know what a vector is, or how to find out about it. Visit cppreference.com to get started, or read a basic C++ book.

Comment: @Arrieta I think the OP made it quite clear the the `Pair` code was _as given_ in an assignment. To user1082764: I'm not providing this code to (a) let you copy it (b) show off; I'm merely showing it so you can have _some_ sense of how complicated this task should be, approximately. This is to avoid hours and hours of digging in the wrong direction - I know how that works :/

Comment: @sehe sure. But I feel the point remains: if one is dealing with C++ code of any but the most basic complexity, I believe one should be willing (and capable) to learn the basic concepts of the Standard Library (not only the concept themselves, but where to find information about them). Nice answer, btw.

Comment: @user1082764 I'm reading from stdin (`cin`) (mainly because it's convenient for demonstration). On Coliru, click the 'Edit' button to see the response document. To read from a file, simply replace `cin` by an instance of [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Comment: I'd write the same, except without the magic-number return code and droopy `{`s. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've always hated having to have extra includes just to say `EXIT_FAILURE`. And having user-define exit codes symbolically is certainly overkill for this short sketch :/

Comment: @sehe: Still, you're kinda promoting a bad practice to newbies :(